# User can't communicate with proxy

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, imaplib

I'm implementing an IMAP proxy which securely communicates with a client.However, I have a problem when handshaking.

The code of my proxy is:

```
self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.sock.bind((host, port))
ssock, addr = self.sock.accept()

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
self.conn_client = context.wrap_socket(ssock)
```

And I receive the error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:833)
```

The code of my tests is:

```
M = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(IP_PROXY)
```

And I receive the error:

```
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNKNOWN_PROTOCOL] unknown protocol (_ssl.c:777)
```

However, when the code of the proxy is:

```
self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
self.sock.bind((host, port))
ssock, addr = self.sock.accept()
self.conn_client = ssl.wrap_socket(ssock, certfile=CERT, server_side= True)
```

It correctly works but I don't want to use certificate.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It correctly works but I don't want to use certificate.

SSL/TLS is almost everywhere used with a certificate to make sure that the client is talking to the expected server and not to some man in the middle. If you don't want to use a certificate you need to either use a different kind of authentication (like PSK) or use no authentication at all ("anonymous authentication" - very bad idea).

In any way you would need to set the relevant ciphers to enable this alternative authentication on both client and server.  This can be done with the `ciphers` attribute to `wrap_socket` on the server side and in your client code it could probably be done by constructed a SSLContext with the necessary ciphers and using the `ssl_context` argument to specific the context to be used in `IMAP4_SSL`.

But this is only for your specific Python based IMAP client. Don't expect that you will be able to configure commonly used IMAP clients like Thunderbird or Outlook to be usable with a server without certificates. And like I said, it is a bad idea in the first place.